# How Efficient is copySign(mag, sign) in Java?

Tags: java

How is Java's `copySign` method different from the following code (in terms of software structure and efficiency?

```java
if (sign < 0)
    return -1*magnitude;
else
    return magnitude;
```

versus
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l2138

```java
return Double.longBitsToDouble((Double.doubleToRawLongBits(sign) &
                                        (DoubleConsts.SIGN_BIT_MASK)) |
                                       (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(magnitude) &
                                        (DoubleConsts.EXP_BIT_MASK |
                                         DoubleConsts.SIGNIF_BIT_MASK)));
    }
```

I understand part of it has to do with dealing with Java's version of infinity and "not a number" (`NaN`), but past that is there anything inherently special about the long and complex version?

Comment: There is negative zero too, to expand on your list of "weird edge cases"

Comment: You seem to be asking a different question in the title than in the body. Do you want to ask "How efficient is `copySign`?" or "How is `copySign` different from my own implementation of it?"